# Single Disk to ZFS mirror or RAID-1

Tags: server, raid, zfs

Already read [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301828/extend-existing-single-disk-zfs-with-a-mirror-without-formating-the-existing-hdd) but in this case the user already had a ZFS filesystem.

I got a server where the OS is running from a single SSD. So if this SSD fails, the server is "gone".
Now I got a second SSD with the same storage capacity and my goal is get a ZFS mirror without reinstalling the whole OS.

Is that possible? How would I do that? I would also be okay with a RAID-1 setup, but from what I've read online ZFS is the superior system.

Thanks in advance for any help

davesie

Answer (score 1):

This is feasible if your disk filled for less than 45% of its space (assume it as /dev/sda).

To do so you need:

- partitioning your second drive (/dev/sdb) to 2 partitons with equal size.
- create second mirrored zfs pool from created partitions. E.g. `zpool create tank /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdb2`
- create necessary datasets on new pool
- copy your OS disk to new tank partition (using zfs send for instatnce)
- reconfigure grub to boot from a new pool
- reboot from new pool
- now destroy your old pool
- clear zfs data from sda disk using `zpool labelclear ...`
- replace one of devices (/dev/sdb1 partition) in your new pool with /dev/sda, wait for resilvering completion
- install grub to your sda device
- reboot to ensure your server is bootable from /dev/sda
- detach /dev/sdb2 partition from tank pool
- clear /dev/sdb partition table
- replace /dev/sdb2 partition in tank pool with /dev/sdb and wait for resilvering completion
- install grub to your sdb device

I assume that you do not have the ability to temporary backup your system disk somewhere. So I recommend training on some local VM first. Good luck!